# Show all limit lines in MP Android Line Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to build and android application with MP Android chart v 2.0.9 and my problem is i'm affecting 4 limit lines to my chart but it displaying just two.
Any solution?

```
 LimitLine llg1 = new LimitLine(Charts.refrms , "");
            llg1.setLineWidth(2f);
            llg1.setLineColor(greencolor);
            holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(llg1);
            LimitLine llr1 = new LimitLine(Charts.dgrms , "");
            llr1.setLineWidth(2f);
            holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(llr1);
            LimitLine lly1 = new LimitLine(Charts.pralrms , "");
            lly1.setLineWidth(2f);
            lly1.setLineColor(yellowcolor);
            holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(lly1);
            LimitLine llo1 = new LimitLine(Charts.alrms , "");
            llo1.setLineWidth(2f);
            llo1.setLineColor(orangecolor);
            holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(llo1);
            holder.lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            holder.lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(Charts.rms, "");
            //dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
//            dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
//            dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
            dataset.setDrawValues(false);
            holder.lineChart.animateY(5000);
            LineData data = new LineData(Charts.measdate, dataset);
            holder.lineChart.setData(data);
            holder.lineChart.setDescription("RMS");
            holder.lineChart.setDescriptionTextSize(20);
```

Comment: Have you written some code? It would be great for us to be able to see it.

Comment: yes i added now

Comment: Are you sure values of `Charts.refrms`, `Charts.dgrms`, `Charts.pralrms` and `Charts.alrms` are all different?

Comment: yes they are different

Comment: there are 0.0xx values and they are bigger values

Comment: Maybe try using the latest version of the library (3.0.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to fix the y axis min and max value holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(Charts.dgpeak+2); holder.lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0f);